# In Linux, How to check if a file is being locked (fuser and lsof is not giving the expected result)

Tags: linux

On a Linux server i have 4 users (A, B, C, D) who can write files to /apps/tmp directory. When A is writing a large file (say 10GB) to this folder, i was expecting B, C, D should be able to know if the file is fully written by using 'fuser' or 'lsof' commands. But these commands are showing the in-progress file, only the same user (A) is issuing these commands. If B, C, D issues these commands, it's now showing the file (even when it's partially uploaded)

Output from "A" user
$ fuser /apps/tmp/Test.txt

/apps/tmp/Test.txt: 38637

Output from B, C, D users shows nothing

$ fuser /apps/tmp/Test.txt
$

How can we find which process is writing/locking a file by logging as a different user.

Steps we followed to reproduce this issue,

Step 1) Open putty session and Login to Server1 as user A,

```
$ cd /apps/tmp 
$ cp /tmp/Test.txt /apps/tmp/. (This a 100GB file and will take 5 mins to copy)
```

While file copy is still in-progress Perform Step 2 and 3

Step 2) Open a new putty session and Login to Server1 as user A (this gives the expected output that the file copy is still in-progress)

```
$ cd /apps/tmp 
$ fuser /apps/tmp/Test.txt 
/apps/tmp/Test.txt: 38637
```

Step 3) Open a new putty session and Login to Server1 as user B or C or D (this doesn't give any output)

```
$ cd /apps/tmp 
$ fuser /apps/tmp/Test.txt 
$
```

Comment: Only `root` can see openings by other users. It doesn't look like you're doing this as root.

Comment: Most programs that write to files don't lock them. This is normally only done in applications where multiple processes are expected to be updating the file and need to coordinate.

Comment: If you want to wait for a file to be written and closed, use `inotifywait`.

Comment: For this to be testable, we need a [mre] that shows how the other processes opened the file in question. Note that just having a file open for write is not the same as having an exclusive lock on it -- multiple processes can open the same file for write at the same time (Windows is the only major platform where the default semantics don't work that way, and taking Windows-centric assumptions elsewhere is a fast route to bugs).

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for the details. We were running similar process in a Solaris server and even the non root users (A, B, C, D) were able to see the files that are being written by other users. Also currently we don't have inotifywait installed, i need to see if we can get that installed

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Steps we followed,
1) Open putty session and Login to Server1 as user A, 
cd /apps/tmp
cp /tmp/Test.txt (this is a 100GB file) to /apps/tmp - This will take 5 mins. (while file copy is still in-progress check Step 2 and 3) 

2) Open a new putty session and Login to Server1 as user A (this gives the expected output that the file copy is still in-progress)
$ cd /apps/tmp
$ fuser /apps/tmp/Test.txt
/apps/tmp/Test.txt: 38637

3) Open a new putty session and Login to Server1 as user B or C or D (this doesn't give any output)
$ cd /apps/tmp
$ fuser /apps/tmp/Test.txt
$

Comment: @Santhosh, [edit] that information into the question. Content critical to answering should not be in comments only.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I've added the information to the question section. Thx.